# Why jruby JVM takes forever to load when using jruby-9.1.1.0 and rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, jvm, jruby

I am doing some modifications in the logstash-translate plugin and writing some tests in the process. I am not used to use java virtual machine to program in ruby, but I think it is not reasonable that it takes minutes to load the necessary files to run less than 20 tests.
I am already using the --dev flag in JRUBY_OPTS, what else can I do?

Comment: Does an empty Rails or Ruby project take that long to spin up?

Comment: @tadman thank for your interest. Actually I was using a virtual machine with 1GB of ram for development.
After giving it an extra 1GB rspec is running just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a virtual machine with 1GB of ram for development. After giving it an extra 1GB rspec is running just fine.

Comment: Java itself often uses ~300MB depending on the version and platform. 1GB is pretty tight for JRuby.